# How do I defeat an enemy with a parry?

Tags: achievements, ps3, marvel-infinity-gauntlet

I'm stuck on one last trophy for Marvel Super Hero Squad: The Infinity Gauntlet:

> **Take that, Villain!**
>   Defeated an enemy with a parry.

I've looked up a couple guides and they seem to say the same thing:

> This trophy will pop up during natural gaming. Block an enemy’s attack with [circle] and then hit [square] immediately after to execute a parry.

Well, it certainly didn't come with natural gameplay and I haven't had any problems getting the rest of the trophies. But this one still eludes me. No matter what I try, I can't seem to get this to work. I hold [circle] to block and then immediately hit [square], the guy dies, and nothing happens.

Can anyone shed some light or be more specific on what needs to happen? Obviously I'm doing something wrong and can't figure out what it is. I figure since it says "Defeated" they have to die from the hit, so I tried weakening the enemy first, then blocking and attacking so they die instantly.

Are there any specific enemies that are easier to do this with, on specific levels? I've been trying this for hours along with finishing heroic feats and now I've pretty much finished everything else and am still left with this.

Comment: I haven't played this game, and this is based solely on a hunch, this may not apply to your case, but here goes: Usually a parry occurs when you block an enemy attack just in time. Rather than holding O, try pressing O just as the enemy's attack is about to hit, then when the attack is blocked, attack with Square. Let me know if this helped...

Comment: @JohnoBoy: That seemed to work. At least, when I tried specifically doing that it gave me the trophy. There were so many enemies around me I just kind of started pressing circle and square back and forth to see what happened.

Comment: @JohnoBoy: Yes, it helped me immensely. Even if it was over a month later before I got around to trying. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parrying requires you to block just as the attack hits, not before it.

Rather than holding O, try pressing O just as the enemy's attack is about to hit, then when the attack is blocked, attack with Square